# How do I print a Word Document (.docx) created in ASP.NET MVC (Server side) on the Browser (Client-side) in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, ms-word, document

I am creating a Word Document in ASP.NET MVC C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
The document gets created successfully and the document gets downloaded on the client-side in the Browser.

However, I would also like to have another functionality on my site where the created document goes directly to Print Dialog instead of just getting downloaded on the client side.

I could not figure out a way to achieve this. If it cannot be done directly is there any free or paid third party control that can help me print the document within my web-site ?

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Nope, though you could ask word to export a pdf. That would normally launch in the browser which can print it.

Comment: You can't. Browsers don't have any built-in way to view Word docs so unless the user has configured their browser to open it with some plugin (which 99% of the world hasn't done), the browser will prompt them to download the file. Google Docs Viewer allows the Word document to be seen as a (read-only) document rather than an image (as it was previously working), so you can actually select and copy from the displayed document into another document.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/picssel/vfu581c2/) **JS Fiddle**